# Determining the content of a link

Tags: php

Is there any PHP function that defines whether a given link is a video, picture or neither.

For example:

```
$link = www.example.com/342kddd23
$a = phpfunction($link);
```

If `$link` is a video link; `$a = 1,` if `$link` is a picture link `$a = 2`, if `$link` is not defined (it could be a normal link) `$a = 0`.

Is that possible? If so, are there any existing functions like that?

Comment: your link: $link = www.xxx.com/342kddd23 is it to youtube videos and pictures or actual files of videos and pictures because if its files you can just do a detect on the file extension.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't exist but you can make your own function. It can be based on domain or extension or both...

For example you can list most common video and pics hosting and check if domain correspond.

Very basic:

```
$videos_services =  array('www.youtube.com', 'www.vimeo.com');
$pics_services    =  array('www.flickr.com', 'www.imageshack.us');

function urlType($myUrl)
{
   $url  = parse_url($myUrl);
   $host = $url['host'];

   if(in_array($host, $videos_services))
   {
       return 1;
   }
   elseif(in_array($host, $pics_services))
   {
       return 2;
   }
   else
   {
       return 0;
   }
}
```

becareful, it's a very simple example but you have to deal with url like http://youtube.com or http://www.youtu.be etc.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it would think that http://www.youtube.com/yt/about/ (for example) was a video.

Comment: Yes, but with this solution you'll just end up endlessly tweaking the rules, but I guess this is the only viable solution if you're talking about a URL to a page that *might* contain a video as opposed to a direct link to a image/video.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe such a library exists (there's no built-in function I'm aware of).

You could of course attempt to develop your own, but you'll endlessly be chasing your tail if you plan to go beyond simply checking to see if there's a known file extension such as ".mp4", ".png", etc. due to the fact that you'll need to construct an increasingly large list of matching URL schemas. (This would also imply that a given link may only return a single type of content, which is often not the case.)

Assuming that you're looking for video and image files themselves (and not simply URLs that contain a video, etc.) an alternative (more accurate) approach would be request each link (perhaps using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with [CURLOPT_HEADER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) enabled), see what content headers are returned (specifically "`Content-Type`") and take things from there.

***Update***

As a follow-up based on @smassey's excellent comment, setting the `CURLOPT_NOBODY` option (once again via [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)) will send a `HEAD` request, hence ensuring you don't actually download any of the content beyond the response headers themselves.

Comment: Adding to this, don't make a normal GET/POST request but instead send an HTTP HEAD request as to not explode your bandwidth/max_execution_time while trying to download mp4s ;) The HTTP HEAD request is answered with *only* the headers and not the actual content. Cheers -

Comment: @smassey Speaks wise words. I've updated my answer to incorporate this.